# Какой знак нужно поставить после слова "главное" в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Серые, голубые, зелёные, но главное (?) светлые.

Answer (score 1):

**Где же контекст?**

Допустим такой вариант:

1) *Какие тона? Можно любые. Серые, голубые, зелёные, но, **главное**, светлые.*

Сравнить: *Серые, голубые, зелёные, но **обязательно (только) светлые.***

В данном случае **противительный** союз НО относится к прилагательному, а вводное слово ***главное*** обособляется.

2) Похожий  текст можно записать так: *Какие тона? Можно любые — серые, голубые, зелёные. **Но главное — светлые.***

Здесь НО — **присоединительный** союз, ***главное*** — субстантивированное прилагательное (оно имеет значение существительного).
Подтекст такой: Но главное — чтобы они были светлые.